# How many VPS do I need for my website?

Tags: mysql, vps, web-hosting

I made a website which aims at simulating a trading market. There are a list of prices and corresponding volumes that people want to purchase. Users can purchase at any price any time. My website retrieves the prices and volumes from my database every 2 seconds (I have to update the user's browser frequently to allow them to see the current market). Users' database INSERT query can be sent any time if they purchase.

I used ajax to post or get data from my database (sometimes nested ajax calls). So, every 2 seconds, each user will send or retrieve data by using more than 20 database queries (in order to show a users the current prices and volumes). Also, I may have 200 users at a time.

I was not using VPS before, and I got banned because of using too much CPU resources on my host. Now, I've purchased VPS*2 from a hosting servers. I have:

CPU Speed: 2000 Mhz

Memory: 2048 MB

Disk Space: 20000 MB

Bandwidth: 2000 GB

Connection: 40 Mb/s

Dedicated IP's 2 IP's

Is this enough for my 200 users? Also, which VPS OS is suitable for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Should be plenty so long as you set things up right and code it intelligently.

I've only ever used CentOS, so that'd be my go-to recommendation.  They're all much of a muchness really, just pick the one that you're most familiar with.  Time is expensive.